# Wicket: How to add substring to every error message?

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

We are using wicket 6.

Both Session and Component classes have error() method to display an error. However in both cases these methods are final.

Is there any other universal way to add postfix to any error message? (we are looking to add error id)

Edit:

We have hundreds of files of code which already uses error() method from both Session and Component, so massive refactoring is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can add arbitrary message objects to a Wicket component:

```
component.error(new ErrorCode(code));
```

With a custom FeedbackPanel you can then display the error code as needed:

```
protected Component newMessageDisplayComponent(String id, FeedbackMessage message)
{
    Serializable rawMessage = message.getMessage();
    if (rawMessage instanceof ErrorCode) {
       // create custom component to display a text and/or code
       ...
    } else {
       return super.newMessageDisplayComponent(id, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: We already have error("Some error") calls in all our components all over the place. I was looking for a way to uniformly add a postfix to all of them.

Comment: OK, so just do: return super.newMessageDisplayComponent(id, message + postfix);